# How can I add search functionality to a ListView?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, listview, textbox

I have a TextBox and a ListView on a Form. The ListView is connected to MS SQL database.
I want write text in the TextBox and search the ListView for this text in one of its columns.

I added this code to the `TextChanged` event handler of a TextBox.
What is wrong in this code?

```
Private Sub WyszukajUmowyNajmow()
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

    Try
        sql = "SELECT UN.NUMER_UMOWY, UN.DATA_UMOWY, RO.RODZAJ_NAJMU, CZ.WYSOKOSC_CZYNSZU_NETTO, CZ.CZYNSZ_WYRAZONY, CZ.ZAPLATA_CZYNSZU, 
              CZ.TERMIN_ZAPLATY, UN.DATA_OD, UN.DATA_DO, UN.WYSOKOSC_KAUCJI_NETTO, CHP.NR_FABRYCZNY, CHP.NR_REJESTRACYJNY 
              FROM N_UMOWY_NAJMOW AS UN
              INNER JOIN N_CZYNSZ AS CZ
              ON UN.ID_CZYNSZU = CZ.ID_CZYNSZU
              INNER JOIN N_CHARAKTERYSTYKA_POZ_POJAZDU AS CHP
              ON UN.ID_CHARAKTERYSTYKI_POJAZDU = CHP.ID_CHARAKTERYSTYKI_POJAZDU
              INNER JOIN N_RODZAJ_NAJMU AS RO
              ON UN.ID_RODZAJU_NAJMU = RO.ID_RODZAJU_NAJMU
              WHERE CHP.NR_FABRYCZNY LIKE ' % " & TextBox.Text & " % ' "

        connection()
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        DataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        listaUmowNajmow.Items.Clear()

        Dim x As ListViewItem

        Do While DataReader.Read = True
            x = New ListViewItem(DataReader("NUMER_UMOWY").ToString)
            x.SubItems.Add(DataReader("DATA_UMOWY"))
            x.SubItems.Add(DataReader("RODZAJ_NAJMU").ToString)
            x.SubItems.Add(DataReader("WYSOKOSC_CZYNSZU_NETTO").ToString)
            x.SubItems.Add(DataReader("CZYNSZ_WYRAZONY").ToString)
            x.SubItems.Add(DataReader("ZAPLATA_CZYNSZU").ToString)
            x.SubItems.Add(DataReader("DATA_OD"))
            x.SubItems.Add(DataReader("DATA_DO"))
            x.SubItems.Add(DataReader("TERMIN_ZAPLATY").ToString)
            x.SubItems.Add(DataReader("NR_REJESTRACYJNY").ToString)
            x.SubItems.Add(DataReader("NR_FABRYCZNY").ToString)
            x.SubItems.Add(DataReader("WYSOKOSC_KAUCJI_NETTO").ToString)
            listaUmowNajmow.Items.Add(x)
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        command.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *"ListView is connected to MS SQL database"*. No it isn't. The WinForms `ListView` doesn't even support data-binding, never mind direct database connection. If you are displaying data from a database then you should almost certainly be using a `DataGridVeiw`, which does support data-binding.

Comment: Include your any error messages, current program behavior/output and expected or desired behavior/output.

Comment: So i must use only DataGridView ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any errors when compile this code, but when app is running then i want to write in TextBox (event TextBox_TextChanged) then on ListView i don't see any items, but should be there. When Form load i see on ListView items from MS SQL database. Someone know what is wrong with this code?